How to solve "Torch was not compiled with flash attention" warning?
I am using the Vision Transformer as part of the CLIP model and I keep getting the following warning:
..\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:5504: UserWarning: 1Torch was not compiled with flash attention. (Triggered internally at ..\aten\src\ATen\native\transformers\cuda\sdp_utils.cpp:455.)
  attn_output = scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, attn_mask, dropout_p, is_causal)

The code works, but I'm guessing that it's not as fast as possible since there's no FA.
I have tried running the ViT while trying to force FA using: with torch.nn.attention.sdpa_kernel(torch.nn.attention.SDPBackend.FLASH_ATTENTION): and still got the same warning.
For reference, I'm using Windows 11 with Python 3.11.9 and torch 2.3.1+cu121.

Not from Stack Overflow, but I found a similar Github Issue discussing what seems to achieve what you want: https://github.com/oobabooga/text-generation-webui/issues/5705

for this setup:
Windows 10
CUDA Version:  12.4
Pytorch Version: 2.4.1
Flash Attention Version: 2.6.3

run from CMD line by line:
set USE_FLASH_ATTENTION=1
pip uninstall torch
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124
pip install build
pip install cmake
pip install ninja
pip install wheel
pip install flash-attn --no-build-isolation 

then in your code whn you initialize the model pass the attention method (Flash Attention 2) like this:
model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16, attn_implementation="flash_attention_2").to('cuda')

from python you can always check the versions you are using, run this code:
import torch

# Check what version of PyTorch is installed
print(torch.__version__)

# Check the current CUDA version being used
print("CUDA Version: ", torch.version.cuda)

# Check if CUDA is available and if so, print the device name
print("Device name:", torch.cuda.get_device_properties("cuda").name)

# Check if FlashAttention is available
print("FlashAttention available:", torch.backends.cuda.flash_sdp_enabled())



There are several steps I took to successfully install flash attention after encountering a similar problem and spending almost half a day on it.
First, you have to make sure the PyTorch version installed on your device is compatible with the CUDA version, although I believe this is a small problem.
Secondly, you would also have to download the Visual Studio Tools related to C++. After reading up online, it has to do with the fact that certain python package wheels do not automatically come with C++ libraries so you would have to manually download it.
Additionally, when downloading them, you would also most likely have to keep in mind to download CUDA 12.4 or later ones to ensure compatibility.
Finally, according to their website, you would have to ensure the ninja package is installed for faster installation, if not you could take 6 hours like my installation. And make sure to use pip install flash-attn --no-build-isolation.
However, a word of caution is to check the hardware support for flash attention. There are only few advanced hardware GPUs they support currently, and I did not read this so I went through all of this for nothing as my GPU is not supported by flash attention.
Hope this works for you!

Thank you for the answer! I have done so (the install of flash-attn was successful), but I still get the same warning. Is there anything else I need to do or modify the code somehow to utilize flash attention?

Hm... for me after installing it worked as intended apart from the fact that my GPU was not supported... maybe your GPU/hardware is also not supported? Or maybe there is another line of code to write to run torch with FA? For my case, it was using HuggingFace library so I had to run the code attn_implementation="flash_attention_2",
so maybe addition of a few more lines of code is the solution for you too.
